# CORS issue between Angular2 and WebAPI application on two different servers

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've come across an issue with CORS between an Angular2 application and a WebAPI application when my Angular2 app is running on my own machine but the WebAPI app is running on IIS on a web server. Interestingly, everything works fine if I run both the applications on my own machine

I get the following error in Chrome:-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fowebtst01l:81/FilePusher.Service/api/version. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I've installed the CORS nuget package in my WebAPI application and enabled it in my WebApiConfig class using

```
            var attrib = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") {SupportsCredentials = true};
        config.EnableCors(attrib);
```

I've also added this code into my Global.asax.cs file:-

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            string header = Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0];

            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", header);
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

But to no avail. Can anyone help with this?

Note that if I remove the code to enable CORS and instead add in the following settings into my Web.config then I get this error when running everything locally:-

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the Authorize attribute to both of my controllers that I was calling from Angular2. By using withCredentials in my http calls in my Angular2 app, I had to also add the Authorize attribute on my controllers in order to get it to work. I also had to enable Anonymous authentication as well as Integrated/Windows Authentication on IIS in order to get this to all work